# Configuration for Yahoo API for localhost development

Tags: web-applications, web, yahoo-api

What should I enter for Home Page URL and Callback Domain if I want to develop a web application that uses the Yahoo API locally.  I can't get a secret and publishable key without this.

I'm not sure if asking this question is appropriate here, but any advice, guidance, etc. would be really appreciated.  I'm fairly new to the web application development world.

Comment: For Localhost none of the API works because if you put IP/Localhost then it will redirect to their local system not to your local system. So using login system in localhost is not possible as far as my knowledge is concern.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into issues with the Yahoo API using OAuth on my local development environment. I wanted to use http://localhost in the 'Home Page URL' and 'Callback Domain'. Yahoo wouldn't allow it.

**Option 1**

Since, Yahoo does not let you modify settings of the Apps you register with them, you need to create a new one.  Try this:

1. In the Yahoo Developer Network, go to My Apps and create a new app.
2. Set the `Application Type` to `Installed Application` instead of `Web Application`.
3. The `Home Page URL` and `Callback Domain` will be optional. Set it or don't set it. I believe you can pass in the callback url

**Option 2**

For `Home Page URL` and/or `Callback Domain`, I had some success using a TLD that points back to localhost.  For instance http://lvh.me and all of it's sub-domains just point back to your computer (127.0.0.1).

**Option 3**

Alternately, try using IP address 127.0.0.1 instead for `Home Page URL` and/or `Callback Domain`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't verify the domain.
2. Don't make the web version, but a desktop app.