# Webpack to run locally on a custom domain without socket issues

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, create-react-app

My setup:

Using react-create-app using a proxy to use a server API with it. ([Using create-react-app with a server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGAeD.png))

Since Yahoo oAuth2 API does not allow localhost:**** or 127.0.0.1:**** in their URL callbacks [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795939/configuration-for-yahoo-api-for-localhost-development).

There for I have to first create a Nginx proxy to send localhost:3000 to port 80 and then I reroute localhost to -> mywebsite.dev

Alright, this setup works fine if I am using a simple node.js server:

1. Press login button to yahoo (/auth)
2. On server authenticate and send to callback URL (mywebsite.dev/callback)
3. After agreeing with yahoo conditions I get rerouted to /callback and I can use the API just fine

But when using the create-react-app setup I am running into issues.

A)When starting the server everything work's fine, I go to mywebsite.dev but then I get this:
[image: error msg] 
I get the error the webpack-dev-server is trying to listen to localhost:**** and since the url is mywebsite.dev it is giving this issue, and I am not able to fix it!

So the question is how to I let Webpack know that my local server is at mywebsite.dev not localhost:**** ?

Related : [link 1 - simular issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31191884/set-up-webpack-to-run-locally-on-a-custom-domain-over-https), [link 2 - node.js custom domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14303690/nodejs-domain-without-port-number)

Answer (score 0):

you can specify host while running web pack

```
webpack-dev-server --port 3000 --hot --host mywebsite.dev
```

or you can listen

```
 var server = new WebpackDevServer(webpack(webpackConfig), {
    ...
  });
  server.listen(port, "mywebsite.dev", function(err) { ...
```

Comment: That does not solve it, if you do that then the URL becomes http://mywebsite.dev:3000 instead of mywebsite.dev .

Comment: remove --port 3000

Comment: Same happens it just uses the default port :8080 :S